# Телеграм бот - ждать ответ после отправки сообщения

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть телеграм бот написанный на `python` с модулем **telebot**. Допустим я прошу полбзователя ввести его имя, затем ввести его возраст и т.д. То есть суть в том, что я хочу отправлять рользователю сообщение, затем подождать его ответ (добавить ответ в переменную), после послать другое сообщение и ждать ответа (добавить ответ в переменную).

Тоесть должно получиться так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно использовать sql или json и значение из 1 ответа вставлять в json файл или sql таблицу для каждого отдельного пользователя telegram создает chatID можно сделать такие поля и для каждого пользователя вставлять в таблицу  что-то типа: chatid = 23048902, age = 34, name = 'arthur' (см. sql, mysql, sqlite3) а потом получать эти данные, на пример пользователь что-то пишет и для любого пользователя вы можете посмотреть эти данные найдя его имя и возраст по уникальному chatID